# EWS attachment id vs attachment contentid

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm using exchange api to manage user's emails in my application.

As a part of this module I have to deal with  email attachments to enable users
to download or add attachments in their emails.

In the `fileAttachment` object I have `id` and `contentid` properties but I can't understand what is

the difference between them besides that `id` is read only and `contentid` isn't.
What is the purpose of each one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AttachmentId is what you use in EWS in the GetAttachment operation to get a specific attachment. The ContentId should be equivalent to the Mime Content-Id header see https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2392.txt it is used for In-line attachments see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh532564%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx

Cheers
Glen

Comment: So while creating a new Email with attachment can I set a unique identifier to the ContentId?

Comment: Yes as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa565006(v=exchg.150).aspx . Applications can use ContentId to implement their own identification mechanisms